# Sqlite3, c-api, icu collations

Tags: c, sqlite

With help of some guides around I successfully compiled ICU extension for sqlite3 with gcc and get libSqliteIcu.so, with no one error showed. Then I copied this lib to /usr/lib folder. After that I fire sqlite through terminal and ".load libSqliteIcu.so" and then "icu_load_collation („hr_HR“, „CROATIAN");" all without errors or remarks on terminal. Query results are sorted now properly.

What I shold do now to be able to use croatian collation through c-api?

I try:

```
sqlite3_stmt *selStmt;
const char *zSqlSelect = "SELECT sif, name, kat FROM mytable WHERE naziv LIKE 'mala%' ORDER BY naziv COLLATE CROATIAN;";
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, zSqlSelect, -1, &selStmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK )
{
    int cols = sqlite3_column_count(selStmt);
    int result = 0;
    while(true)
    {
        result = sqlite3_step(selStmt);
        if(result == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            for(int col = 0; col < cols; col++)
            {
                printf("%s %s \t", sqlite3_column_name(selStmt,col), "=");
                printf("%s\n", sqlite3_column_text(selStmt, col));
            }
        }
        else break;
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(selStmt);
}
else
    printf("db error: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
```

Error message is "db error: no such collation sequence: CROATIAN".

What do I miss and how to get sqlite3 sort propery by given collation through c-api like I get through command line?

Answer (score 2):

I find solution so here is like an ansewer.
Immediately after opening database this should be donned and then you can use collation name in query to get case insensitive and properly sorted result.
Despite of croatian example I think this can be applyed to all collations supported by ICU.

```
    if (sqlite3_enable_load_extension(db, 1) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
    printf ("loading extensions enabled\n");
    const char* library;

    #if defined(linux)   
        library = "path_to/libSqliteIcu.so";
    #else
        library = "path_to\libSqliteIcu.dll";
    #endif

        if (sqlite3_load_extension(db, library, 0, 0) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            sqlite3_stmt *collation;
            if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "SELECT icu_load_collation('hr_HR', 'CROATIAN');", -1, &collation, 0) != SQLITE_OK)
            printf("db error: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));

            if (collation)
                sqlite3_step(collation);
            else
                printf("Error: collation is not loaded");

            sqlite3_finalize(collation);
        }
        else
            printf ("Error: libSqliteIcu NOT loaded\n");
    }
    else
        printf("Error: enable_load_extension\n");

    if (sqlite3_enable_load_extension(db, 0) == SQLITE_OK) printf ("loading extensions disabled\n");
```

So only one related question left:
How to get case sensitive LIKE searching when we uses sqlite this way?
I try COLLATE BINARY and it is case insensitive again.